# Use the HTML class property in CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML div tag as belows:

```
<div id="cookiemsgbox" class="blue" style="display: block;">
```

This consists of few links and span tags. All of them appear in blue color because of `class=blue;` property.

Now instead of putting it in the html tag I wish to use the class property in the css. 
I have written it as belows:

```
#cookiemsgbox {
 class: blue; }
```

Also tried :

```
#cookiemsgbox {
 class: #364395; }
```

But this does not works. 
 The links and span elemnets appear gray(colorless).

Where am I going wrong ? 
 Please help.
 Thanks :)

Comment: You really need a basic understanding of `CSS`. Class'es are declared like this in `CSS` -> `.blue { color: blue}`

Comment: As @Morpheus already said, you have to look at the basics of CSS. This may help you: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp or http://www.cssbasics.com/

Comment: Why you need HTML class property in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS use `color: blue;`. To understand CSS selectors refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

```
#cookiemsgbox
{
    color: blue;
}
```

**Explaination:**

- `#` selects `id` attribute
- `.` selects `class` attribute.

`#cookiemsgbox` selects the element with `id="cookiemsgbox"`.

`.blue` selects all elements with `class="blue"`

Comment: For valid HTML # should select only one element, because an ID has to be unique ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.blue
    {
       color : blue;
    }
```

OR

```
    #cookiemsgbox
    {
       color : blue;
    }
```